# Insert an PHP array into MySQL with table as variable or dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I have an php array:

```
$cont_array = Array("613:m-ent:id=one","930:m-lk:id=one;x=180;y=79;which=1","1080:m-lev:id=one;");
```

I want to insert it into a MySQL table with table-name as variable, like `$table_name = "user1"`.

In addition, I want to break each array-element by the first `":"` .After executing my php code I get just an empty table.

I need help please. This is my code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','prueba');

$cont_array = Array("613:m-ent:id=one","930:m-clk:id=one;x=180;y=79;which=1","1080:m-lev:id=one;");
$table_name = "user1";


$sql_1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `".$table_name."`;";
$sql_1 .= "CREATE TABLE `".$table_name."` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `usercod` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `pid` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `time` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        `all_act` varchar(1000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";

mysqli_multi_query($connection,$sql_1);


foreach ($cont_array as $row){
    $break_e = explode(':', $row, 2);
    $sql="INSERT INTO`".$table_name."` (usercode,pid,name,time,all_act) VALUES ("user","pid_value","user_name",'$break_e [0]','$break_e [1]');";
    mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}
?>
```

**This is what I get:**
[image: This is what I get:]

**This is what I would like to get:**
[image: This is what I would like to get:]

Comment: Your create uses `usercod`, but the insert uses `usercode`

Comment: Also if you look at the display of the code, your quotes in the SQL are incorrect.

Comment: You should enable [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in your script, during development.

Comment: In addition to enabling the PHP errors, you can also add the following after the `mysqli_query` function: `mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));`

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL seem to have issue check below SQL statement.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (usercod,pid,name,time,all_act) VALUES  ('user','pid_value','user_name','".$break_e [0]."','".$break_e [1]."')";
```

Comment: Nope...still not correct though. `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Take a look at the OPs table schema.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Synapselndia. I replaced your piece of code. However, I still get empty table. Considering the table-name fix, my code works, but I need to give it as variable.

Comment: Hi JustBaron. The first column is is AUTO_INCREMENT, so I just need to insert six variables.

Comment: @EfrainNoa No...5 variables.